# Read/write to memory that was previously allocated via JNI

Tags: java-native-interface

I use macros to allocate memory via JNI and then write to that memory.

```scala
@MacroAllocator
case class SomeCaseClass(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)
```

3 * INT.BYTES = 12, so it means I need to allocate 12 bytes of memory.

I wrote a buffer that stores offheap objects. and if i already get address of buffer i can reuse that address to write/read.

```c
typedef struct {
    uint8_t *buf;
    size_t   size;
} buf_t;
```

via jni i'm allocating memory (assume it's at compile time)

```c
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_some_package_com_1alloc(JNIEnv *env, jobject self, jint size) {
    globalenv = env;
    buf_t buf;
    buf_alloc(&buf, (size_t) size);

    jlong buf_addr = (jlong)buf.buf;

    return buf_addr;
}
```

and then i'm trying to write something to that buf, it's okay too (compile time too)

```c
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_some_package_com_1write_1int(JNIEnv *env, jobject self, jint value, jint idx, jlong buf_addr) {
    globalenv = env;
    uint8_t *buf = (uint8_t*) buf_addr;
    write_int_to_buf_at(buf, idx, value);
    return;
}
```

and when everything is done, i'm trying to read (runtime):

```c
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_some_package_com_read_1int(JNIEnv *env, jobject self, jint idx, jlong buf_addr) {
    globalenv = env;
    uint8_t *buf = (uint8_t*)buf_addr;
    int32_t value = read_int_in_buf_at(buf, (size_t) idx);
    return value;
}
```

UPD: read_int_in_buf_at func impl

```c
int32_t read_int_in_buf_at(uint8_t *buf, size_t idx) {

    uint8_t b3 = buf[idx + 3];
    uint8_t b2 = buf[idx + 2];
    uint8_t b1 = buf[idx + 1];
    uint8_t b0 = buf[idx];

    return (b3 << 24) | ((b2 & 255) << 16) | 
           ((b1 & 255) << 8) | (b0 & 255);

}
```

i get some weird results when trying to read: 0, 1234125360, -1342346458, etc.

Comment: Uh, your `alloc` function returns the address of a stack-local `buf`. That sounds like a recipe for disaster. Use `new buf` to allocate a `buf` on the C++ heap instead!

Comment: @Botje, but buf_alloc function dynamically allocates chunk of memory for struct: 

```c
buf_t *buf = (buf_t*)malloc(sizeof(*buf));
```

Comment: That may very well be, but you still return the address of a stack variable in the code that calls it.

Comment: @Botje do you offer me to allocate memory for a pointer? i mean, you know, something like this: 
```c 
int *ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(ptr)); 
```

Comment: You could return `buf.buf` instead.

Comment: To clarify my comment (was on phone): `buf_t buf` is allocated on the stack, but it *contains* a pointer to the heap in its `buf` member. Your `Java_some_package_com_1alloc` method should take the contents of `buf.buf`(the heap address that you reserved) and return it, not the address of the `buf_t` struct on the stack.

Comment: @Botje okay, i'll check it. and so, when i'm trying to read something, at ```Java_some_package_com_read_1int``` i'm need to cast address (buf_addr) to ```(uint8_t*)```? 

```uint8_t *buf = *(uint8_t*)buf_addr;```

Comment: Yes, `buf_addr` would be the address of your allocated memory there.

Comment: @Botje, still get weird results; i did everything as you described

Comment: Please show the exact implementation of `buf_alloc`.

Comment: @Botje with latest fixes

```void buf_alloc(buf_t *buf, size_t size) {
    buf->size = size;
    buf->buf = (uint8_t *)malloc(size * sizeof(uint8_t));
}```

Comment: and you return `buf.buf` from your `_1alloc` function, and you use `uint8_t *buf = *(uint8_t*)buf_addr;`to get at the allocated buffer in your two functions? Please update your question instead of putting information in the comments;

Comment: @Botje, yeah, i'm using ```uint8_t *buf = *(uint8_t*)buf_addr ``` . 

i've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comments, you have to keep in mind that `Java_some_package_com_1alloc` returns the address of allocated memory (`buf.buf`) *NOT* the `buf_t` struct itself.

This means your functions have to change accordingly:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_some_package_com_1write_1int(JNIEnv *env, jobject self, jint value, jint idx, jlong buf_addr) {
    globalenv = env;
    // The `jlong` value is the address of allocated memory 
    uint8_t *buf = (uint8_t*) buf_addr;
    write_int_to_buf_at(buf, idx, value);
}
```

and the reader:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_some_package_com_read_1int(JNIEnv *env, jobject self, jint idx, jlong buf_addr) {
    globalenv = env;
    uint8_t *buf = (uint8_t*) buf_addr;
    int32_t value = read_int_in_buf_at(buf, (size_t) idx);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: i don't know why it doesn't work well...

when i'm trying to get a value at some index im still get weird values, but the last value (for example, when i'm written 3 ints to buffer and if i wanna read int at index 2, it works well) is accessible via calling  ```Java_some_package_com_read_1int```